# How to start a service automatically using broadcastreceivers after booting?

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I am using android 4.4 version.
How to start a service automatically using broadcastreceivers after booting?
Thanks in advance.
UPDATE:
code in manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.prashanthi.trial.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:name=".WordService"></service>
     <receiver android:name=".MyScheduleReceiver" android:enabled="true"
              android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Code in receiver class:

```
   public class MyScheduleReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

      Toast.makeText(context, "Intent Detected.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();        
      System.out.println("This is MyShedularReceiver");

   Intent service = new Intent(context, WordService.class);
      //service.setAction(RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED);
    context.startService(service);
  }

   }
```

Code for service class:

```
 public class WordService extends Service{
public void onCreate() {

    super.onCreate();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent
            .getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()
        + (5 * 1000), pendingIntent);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm set in 5 seconds",
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
   }

}
```

In main activity I have code to display notifications. But the problem is, receiver class itself not triggered after running the app in emulator....can u please suggest me where I went wrong?

Comment: Similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784441/trying-to-start-a-service-on-boot-on-android?rq=1

Comment: exactly!! I tried that one but did not work for me..

Comment: Then tell us that in your question. [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: @Niek Thanks for reply..I updated the code what I tried can you please check that out?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Follow this step one by one.

Create this Receiver class:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;


public class BootUpReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        /****** For Start Activity *****/
        Intent i = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);  
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);  

        /***** For start Service  ****/
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, ServiceClassName.class);
        context.startService(myIntent);
    }   

}
```

In `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<receiver 
    android:enabled="true" 
    android:name=".BootUpReceiver"
    android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<service
    android:name=".ServiceClassName"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true" >
</service>
```

Comment: Thanks for showing code ..but did this work for you...I tried exactly as u said but did not work for me :(

Comment: But through this code I have done three live client projects. Can you please show your code.

Comment: Updated the code which I have tried I hope you can help me out with this...

Comment: "receiver class itself not triggered after running the app in emulator....can u please suggest me where I went wrong?" in emulator how the receiver will triggered ? for triggering you will need to boot up the device. Please check your code from real device first.

Comment: so after installing that project in mobile, I need to boot it again...am i correct?

Comment: Yes....... you can also test it from tablet. i think you are already in right direction. please check it.

Comment: it's my pleasure that your code will workable .

Comment: Didn't work until I added <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" /> to manifest

Comment: @ImmaWake plz follow my code, I have already mention this.

Comment: @SatyakiMukherjee
I could also only get it working after inserting the line Imma Wake mentioned.
I am on nougat.